# Distributions in the Weibull max-domain of attraction

Tags: extreme-value, weibull-distribution

Can I please have a few examples of distributions that, when block-max sampled for extreme values, are in the max-domain of attraction of the Weibull distribution? I know the Beta distrution is, but any other examples?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan Beirlant et al. "Statistics of Extremes: Theory and Applications" give a few examples in their table 2.2, uniform distribution, reversed Burr. Not exactly "interesting", but I will work with that and, so will close this question. Thanks.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Statistics_of_Extremes/GtIYLAlTcKEC?hl=en&gbpv=0